# python bs4 or lxml to solve this?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

In the website I parser look like this. I'm new to Python by the way.

```
<ul class="main-info-list">
    <li class="span">
        <div class="title">Address</div>
        <div class="value">Bangkok </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="title">Status</div>
        <div class="value">Finish</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="title">Type</div>
        <div class="value">Condo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="title">Section</div>
        <div class="value">Unknown</div>
</ul>
```

How can I make a dictionary like this.

```
Data = {"Address":"Bangkok","title":"Finish","Type":"Condo","Section":"Unknown"}
```

Comment: so what did you try? usually it's encouraged to try yourself first and ask only when you get stuck. You should get a start from here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using bs4**

**Demo:**

```
s = """<ul class="main-info-list">
    <li class="span">
        <div class="title">Address</div>
        <div class="value">Bangkok </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="title">Status</div>
        <div class="value">Finish</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="title">Type</div>
        <div class="value">Condo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="title">Section</div>
        <div class="value">Unknown</div>
</ul>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
d = {}
s = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
for i in s.find_all("li"):
    d[i.find("div", {"class": "title"}).text] = i.find("div", {"class": "value"}).text
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{u'Status': u'Finish', u'Section': u'Unknown', u'Type': u'Condo', u'Address': u'Bangkok '}
```

Comment: I got this error when I try your way.             
                                        
        d[i.find("div", {"class": "title"}).text] = i.find("div", {"class":"value"}).text
        
        AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Looks like your data does not have class=title or class=value